# Windows 10 Fall Patch_SYSPrep Fails_Miracastview issue

Tags: xml, windows, windows-10, sysprep

I know this is a known error, below is what I am getting, what I have done is:

I did the steps in the link below and it did not work:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057974/miracastview-cause-sysprep-error-windows-10-version-1709

Restore the miracastview folder to C:\Windows location and that did not resolve the issue.

Removed the miracastview information from the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Appx\` location and that did not resolve the problem.

I ran the DISM command to clean the image and that did not resolve the problem.

One option is to modify the generalize.xml file, if I do how do I properly remove the following segments from the generalize.xml file?

```
    -<imaging exclude="">
    <assemblyIdentity versionScope="NonSxS" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" version="10.0.16299.15" name="Microsoft-Windows-AppX-Sysprep"/>
    <sysprepOrder order="0x1A00"/>
    <sysprepValidate moduleName="$(runtime.system32)\AppxSysprep.dll" methodName="SysprepGeneralizeValidate"/>
    <sysprepModule moduleName="$(runtime.system32)\AppxSysprep.dll" methodName="SysprepGeneralize"/>
    </imaging>



PackageFullName        : Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
 PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-3429325520-2175502158-1847730730-1001
                          [S-1-5-21-3429325520-2175502158-1847730730-1001]: Installed}


Package Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.

2018-01-17 07:54:11, Error                 SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.

2018-01-17 07:54:11, Error                 SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.


2018-01-17 07:54:11, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 07:54:11, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 07:54:11, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating Sysprep session actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 07:54:11, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 07:54:11, Error      [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2


SYSPRP Package Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not function properly in the sysprep image.

2018-01-17 08:23:42, Error                 SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.

2018-01-17 08:23:42, Error                 SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.

2018-01-17 08:23:42, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralizeValidate' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 08:23:42, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Validate: Error in validating actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 08:23:42, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while validating Sysprep session actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 08:23:42, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
 2018-01-17 08:23:42, Error      [0x0f00d8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while pre-validate sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2
```

Answer (score 1):

I went to the sysprep folder and took ownership of the generalize.xml file. I then gave myself modify permissions and edited the appx information out of the file now sysprep is running.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a Microsoft post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057974/miracastview-cause-sysprep-error-windows-10-version-1709) about the problem. It says

> To work around this issue, use either of the following methods.
>
> **Method 1** On the Windows 10 Version 1709 computer, copy Windows.MiracastView_6.3.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy.xml from
>   C:\Windows.old\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\ to
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository.
>
> **Method 2** Copy the C:\Windows\MiracastView folder from a Windows 10 Version 1703 computer to the Windows 10 Version 1709 computer. Then,
>   restart the computer to let Windows finish uninstalling MiracastView.

Neither of these will work for me. I'd like to try your solution. Will it work on Windows 10 home do you think? If so, what steps do I need to take to modify the generalize.xml file? I don't have permission for it and don't know how to get it.

Comment: remove the following from generalize.xml
 
        -<imaging exclude="">
        <assemblyIdentity versionScope="NonSxS" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" version="10.0.16299.15" name="Microsoft-Windows-AppX-Sysprep"/>
        <sysprepOrder order="0x1A00"/>
        <sysprepValidate moduleName="$(runtime.system32)\AppxSysprep.dll" methodName="SysprepGeneralizeValidate"/>
        <sysprepModule moduleName="$(runtime.system32)\AppxSysprep.dll" methodName="SysprepGeneralize"/>
        </imaging>

Comment: go to the C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\actionfiles location and take ownership of generalize.xml file. Then give your account the modify right.

Comment: Yes, but how do I take ownership and give my account the right to modify it?

Comment: Thank you very much @JediAdministrator, This was the only solution within many that really worked.